# It possible to create a dropdown for a foreignkey?

Tags: django

It possible to create dropdown for class Task() developer field which is a foreignkey? And what is the best way to create it?

developers models.py
from django.db import models

```
class Developer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=21, null=False, blank=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

from developers.models import Developer

class Task(models.Model):
    story = models.ForeignKey(Story)
    developer = models.ForeignKey(Developer)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=360)
    iteration = models.IntegerField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
```

forms.py

```
class AddTask(forms.ModelForm):
    story = forms.ForeignKey(Story)
    developer = forms.ForeignKey(Developer)
    description = forms.CharField(max_length=360)
    iteration = forms.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        fields = ["name", "developer", "description", "iteration"]
        model = Task
```

Comment: That's not your real forms.py, because there is no such thing as `forms.ForeignKey`.

Comment: In any case, a dropdown for a foreign key is the *default* behavour of a model form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a `ModelForm` for you `Developer` model, each foreign key is rendered as a `ModelChoiceField`. The widget for that field is the html select you are looking for.

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

class DeveloperForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model Developer
```

Have a look [at the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/) to get a better grasp of it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

I just needed to use forms.ModelChoiceField().

```
class AddTaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    story = forms.ModelChoiceField(Story.objects.all())
    developer = forms.ModelChoiceField(Developer.objects.all())
    description = forms.CharField(max_length=360)
    iteration = forms.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        fields = ["story", "developer", "description", "iteration"]
        model = Task
```